# Excel file created with Open XML in C# cannot be opened after deployment on AWS

Tags: openxml

I have developed a asp.net core api  that generates an Excel document using Open XML. Locally, the generated Excel file is working perfectly fine, and I can open it without any issues. However, when I deploy the application on AWS and try to open the downloaded Excel file, it prompts me to recover the file, and I am unable to open it.

this is the sample code .

```
        [HttpGet("GenerateExcel")]
        public IActionResult GenerateExcel()
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                // Add a WorkbookPart to the document
                var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart
                var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                // Add a Sheets object to the Workbook
                var sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                // Add a new sheet and specify the sheet name
                var sheet = new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                    SheetId = 1,
                    Name = "Sheet1"
                };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                // Save the changes to the Excel document
                spreadsheetDocument.Close();
            }

            // Set the response headers
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelFile.xlsx");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            // Return the generated Excel file as a FileResult
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return File(memoryStream, Response.ContentType);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: I know it sounds silly but; can you compare the file sizes of your locally created Excel file and the one you downloaded from AWS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The file size is different.

AWS downloaded file size: 3 KB
Locally downloaded file size: 2 KB (working one)

I tried to call the API via Postman. In Postman, we have the option to save responses to a file. I tried saving the response to a file.

when I called the API in local and tried to save the response to a file. The file name is identified as ExcelFile.xlsx. but when I called the API hosted on AWS and tried to save the response to a file, the response was identified as response. json.

Comment: To eliminate HTTP related issues, could you connect to the AWS and check the file there? I would also try eliminate environment related differences.

Comment: I'm new to aws. can you please tell me how to check that in aws. I think file is created in memory .

Comment: I assume by "deployment"  you mean connecting via SSH to a compute instance and running the code there. If that's the case, then save the generated Excel file in code when it's generated and connect via SSH to check the file.

Comment: @Lewis Can you somehow share both files?